# How to use setValue and patchValue in testing angular 2 reactive forms

Tags: forms, unit-testing, angular, testing, angular2-forms

I can't seem to get the correct dependencies in my spec file for testing a new form I've created.

I have 2 passing tests but the 3rd comes to a hault when I use setValue or patchValue to setup my test form data.

Karma in browser gives: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined`

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { NgForm, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


describe('My component test: ', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent],
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
            providers: [] // which provider for setValue/patchValue?
        });

        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        let myComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

    });


    it('sending form values to the service onSubmit method', () => {
        // TypeError: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined
        this.jobForm.patchValue({'title': 'a spec title'}); 
    });
```

The question is: How do I use setValue/patchValue to setup my form object for a test form submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using reactive forms, then you should have the `FormGroup` as a member of the component. This is what you need to access

```
let component;
let fixture;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
        providers: [] // which provider for setValue/patchValue?
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges()
});


it('sending form values to the service onSubmit method', () => {
    // assuming the property on the component is named jobForm
    const form = component.jobForm;

    form.patchValue({'title': 'a spec title'}); 
});
```

Comment: Yes I have, and you are not doing what I'm doing

Comment: It looks like you've added a `form` const but then you don't use it. That's the dif I see. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the diff? You're trying to access `this`. `this` of _what_?. Also you have scoped your variables to the beforeEach, so you can use them out of it. I have moved it to a wider scope

Comment: Thanks for your help but this still has set/patch undefined

Comment: Do you have a `jobForm` property in your component? Is it initialized? Is it a FormGroup instance?

Comment: I see (removed for brevity), I do have a jobForm FormGroup onInit. However you're thinking has shown me that for some reason the actual jobForm is undefined within the it()...

Comment: If it's initialized in the ngOnInit, you need to call `fixture.detectChanges()` for the ngOnInit to be called

Comment: that was it! Wow than you very much for your time and patience. Please update your answer :) #Madprops